# Menu toggle breaks with multiple IDs

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, toggle

I have a menu that is responsive with some media queries that adjusts the menu so it looks good regardless of screen size. The menu uses some JavaScript to create a toggle button, people can click the toggle to see the navigation on smaller screens.

Everything is wrapped in a DIV, if the DIV has a `class`, I have no problems...if the DIV has an `id` the JavaScript doesn't work.

I don't know that much about JavaScript, but it looks like it's declaring a variable. The variable is getting the `id` of the UL, so there should be no conflicts. Is there something I am missing?

The JavaScript:

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
```

The HTML (I tweaked the URLS and classes on the links a bit to condense things here):

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <li><a href="http://url.com/">Home</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://url.com/">Pictures</a>
            <ul class="children">
                <li><a href="http://url.com/">Beaver</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://url.com/">Duck</a>
                    <ul class="children">
                        <li><a href="http://url.com/">Fever</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="http://url.com/">Frog</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
       <li><a href="http://url.com/">Nominations</a></li>
       <li><a href="http://url.com/">Contact</a></li>
       <li class="icon">
           <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
       </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I don't think the CSS is important, because I'm pretty sure this is a JS issue...especially because if I change the outer ID to a class everything works :-)

Live example: http://joshrodg.com/site/

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I basically just ended up using the class since that worked. It would have been nice to use an ID, but since it's working with the class, it's not a huge deal.